# Drop Y value till desired value with ONE x variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to drop the value of Y with one important variable.

Y starts with value of 2.4 and endpoint is 1.7. The problem is I do not know the data between 2.4 and 1.7. (Only clue is it always depends on the value of X and drops til hit 1.7)

If X value is big, Y should drop more. (X value is between 0 ~ 8).

If it is small, it should drop less.

Anyone can give an advice? or a way to perform?

Below is the sample data.

```
Y     X
2.4   1   
?     7  
?     3
?     5
?     8 
1.7   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be :

```
start = 2.4
end = 1.7

df$Y <- c(start, start - cumsum(df$X[-1] * (start - end)/sum(df$X[-1])))

#  X        Y
#1 1 2.400000
#2 7 2.211538
#3 3 2.130769
#4 5 1.996154
#5 8 1.780769
#6 3 1.700000
```

---

Let's break this down. `df$X` is the numbers which determines the magnitude of drop

```
df$X
#[1] 1 7 3 5 8 3
```

When we do

```
(start - end)/sum(df$X[-1])
#[1] 0.02692308
```

It gives us how much 1 unit of drop is. We are ignoring the first value since we already have that number (`2.4`) and we don't want to take that into calculation.

Now we multiply it by `X` so that when the number is 7 we will get higher drop, when it is 1 the drop will be lower

```
df$X[-1] * (start - end)/sum(df$X[-1])
#[1] 0.18846154 0.08076923 0.13461538 0.21538462 0.08076923
```

When you compare this with `df$X` you will notice that

```
0.02692308 * 7 = 0.1884615
0.02692308 * 3 = 0.08076923
0.02692308 * 5 = 0.1346154
```

and so on.

Finally we take cumulative sum (`cumsum`) by adding all these numbers which we subtract it from `start` so that we now have relative drops according to corresponding `X`.

Comment: Nice insight Ronak. I think in this way I can find the coefficient (weight) depends on the number of X. Thank you for explanation.