# Rule based data frame formatting in R

Tags: r, dataframe

This task is next stage task of the question I asked few hours ago. It was about filling out missing value at Y which only decreases depends on the value of X.

[Drop Y value till desired value with ONE x variable? very challenging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174936/drop-y-value-till-desired-value-with-one-x-variable-very-challenging)

Below is the example. When X2 is changing from value 6 to 1, Y value starts from same value (2.4) and end at 1.7.

How do you automatically detect that big change of variable X2. And add the missing value at Y? I can do this task manually and easily finish in 10 minutes. But what if I have abundant data?

```
Y     X1    X2
2.4   9      1
?     7      2
?     3      3
?     5      4
?     8      5
1.7   3      6

2.4   9      1
?     7      2
?     3      3
?     5      4
?     8      5
1.7   3      6
```

Comment: Can you update your question and show the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirment is not very clear, but Updating one column based on the values of the other can be done using mutate as below:

```
df %>% group_by(X2) %>% mutate(Y=ifelse(X2==1, 2.4, ifelse(X2==6, 1.7, 0)))
```

Gives the output:

```
      X1    X2   Y
 1     9     1   2.4
 2     7     2   0  
 3     3     3   0  
 4     5     4   0  
 5     8     5   0  
 6     3     6   1.7
 7     9     1   2.4
 8     7     2   0  
 9     3     3   0  
10     5     4   0  
11     8     5   0  
12     3     6   1.7
```